# What is this parameter in this vector class?

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, namespaces

```
typedef helper::vector<core::collision::DetectionOutput> ContactVector;
```

http://www.sofa-framework.org/api(link to doxygen api documentation) - I can not find the namespace core::collision

```
sofa::core::collision::DetectionOutput
```

I know the typedef means giving it a nickname. And ***helper*** is a namespace within the framework and ***vector*** is a class under the namespace ***helper***. However what I don't understand is the parameters that vector is taking specifically ***core::collision::DetectionOutput***. What is DetectionOuput; is it a class?

Comment: It could be a class, it could be an integer value. It depends on the definition of `helper::vector`

Comment: You should ask this on SOFA's website.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  It would appear so.  And, while we're at it, provide a C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DetectionOutput` is a class. (Ref: [link](http://www.sofa-framework.org/api))
So basically that's a typedef to a vector of DetectionOutput instances. Hope this makes sense.

Quote from their documentation:

> Generic description of a contact point, used for most collision models
>   except special cases such as GPU-based collisions. Each contact point
>   is described by :
>
> elem: pair of colliding elements. id: unique id of the contact for the
>   given pair of collision models. point: contact points on the surface
>   of each model. normal: normal of the contact, pointing outward from
>   the first model. value: signed distance (negative if objects are
>   interpenetrating). deltaT: estimated of time of contact.
>
> The contact id is used to filter redundant contacts (only the contact
>   with the smallest distance is kept), and to store persistant data over
>   time for the response.

Comment: thnx appreciate the quick response

Comment: If this answered your question I would appreciate it if you accept this as the answer :)